# how to find value of corrsponding data attr based on text inside div with jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I have some divs with a name and different values of data attr `data-category`

Now i need the value of `data-category` based on specific text inside the div.

```
<div class='ext-category' data-category="swimpool">Jack</div>
<div class='ext-category' data-category="swimpool">John</div>
<div class='ext-category' data-category="office">Jennifer</div>
<div class='ext-category' data-category="office">Sue</div>
```

In a js function, i can grab the name inside the div:

```
eventReceive: function(info) {
    var name = info.event['name']; // shows me "Jennifer"

}
```

How can i grab the value of `data-category` which belongs to Jennifer?

I tried:

```
var category = $(".ext-category").find(name).attr('data-category');
alert(category); // result: undefined (should be office)
```

Comment: What is `info` object? if it contains the HTMLElement, than you can use `dataset.category` to retrieve data. (i.e. assuming  `info.target` is the HTMLElement: `const category = info.target.dataset.category;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and easy way using [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```js
const getCategoryFromName = (name) => $(`.ext-category:contains(${name})`).data('category')
console.log(getCategoryFromName('Jennifer'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='ext-category' data-category="swimpool">Jack</div>
<div class='ext-category' data-category="swimpool">John</div>
<div class='ext-category' data-category="office">Jennifer</div>
<div class='ext-category' data-category="office">Sue</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `querySelectorAll` loop through the data then check which element has the correct name and return it's data-category value like so

```js
function findByName(name) {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".ext-category");
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].innerText == name) return elements[i].dataset.category; // Credits to vanowm for suggesting .dataset.category rather than .getAttribute
  }
}

console.log(findByName("Jack"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='ext-category' data-category="swimpool">Jack</div>
<div class='ext-category' data-category="swimpool">John</div>
<div class='ext-category' data-category="office">Jennifer</div>
<div class='ext-category' data-category="office">Sue</div>
```

Comment: FYI `data-*` attributes can be accessed via `dataset` property of the element: `return elements[i].dataset.category;`

Comment: Thanks for the FYI, that would definietly make the code more readable, I'll update the answer using it!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```js
var category = $(".ext-category:contains('Jennifer')").attr('data-category');
alert(category);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='ext-category' data-category="swimpool">Jack</div>
<div class='ext-category' data-category="swimpool">John</div>
<div class='ext-category' data-category="office">Jennifer</div>
<div class='ext-category' data-category="office">Sue</div>
```